# Volume mount on SCC as requirement for running Falco

Tags: kubernetes, security, falco

Is it possible to run falco with removing several volume value on scc ? for example just putting hostpath only as value on falco SCC because on the environment (OCP & k8s) only permitted to access hostpath only..

as i see, the value on SCC falco yaml is:

```
Volume:
 - configMap
 - emptyDir
 - secret
 - hostpath
```

thanks

Comment: if you can please share falcofiles to check which you are refering

Comment: I'm using this as references [scc-falco.yaml](https://github.com/falcosecurity/charts/blob/master/falco/templates/securitycontextconstraints.yaml)